# CLI to find out what version my modules are?

Tags: third-party-module, cli

When I run a bin/magento list it doesn't say anything specific about finding out the schema and module versions.

Does anyone know how to figure this out using command line?

Answer (score 5):

There's no way of seeing module version via the bin/magento command. Look in the setup_module table in the database.

Comment: ```mysql -h <db host> -u <db user> -p -D <database> -e 'select * from setup_module;'```

Answer (score 2):

`composer show` is indeed the easiest method (and accurate!).

Comment: and you can grep and get the desire module version `composer show | grep magento/module-tax`

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered composer show lists everything with module version but I'm not sure if it's accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using composer very useful:

```
Flat: composer show -i
Tree: composer show -i -t
-i short for --installed.

-t short for --tree.
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36567536/1978707